# Which linear transformations admit a unique matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a general linear map, there are infinitely many matrix representations. You choose a basis of the vector space, and this gives you a certain matrix for the linear map. You choose a different basis, and this gives you another matrix different from the first. For a linear map that does nothing however, we only get the identity matrix no matter what basis we choose.

It isn't hard to see that the identity matrix will always do what we want from this linear map mechanically. But I feel there is some deeper intuition for why the matrix for this linear map shouldn't change with the basis, without thinking mechanically about the matrix.

On a side note, is there any other linear map where the choice of basis doesn't change the matrix representation or is this the only one?

Comment: The linear maps with that property are those of the form $v\mapsto\lambda v$.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to ask: Why does the identity map have only one matrix representation? Or: Which other linear maps have this property? The title is about the former, but the body of your text is about the latter.

Comment: "*is there any other linear map where the choice of basis doesn't change the matrix representation*" - yes, what about the zero map?

Comment: The zero map is basis invariant as well.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos - The question about other linear maps was a side question. I edited the question to make this clear.

Comment: Another argument: if a map has more than one distinct (complex) eigenvalue then it will have different diagonal matrix representations corresponding to different orderings of a basis of eigenvectors. The only way to avoid this is to have exactly one eigenvalue, forcing the map to be a simple scalar multiplication.

Comment: You should modify the title of your question to something like "which linear transformations admit a unique matrix representation". The title as stated doesn't correspond to the question.

Comment: @Mr.Brown - done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reason, together with a description of all possible examples.

But first, some notation will help greatly. Let's fix the rank of the matrices to be an integer $n \ge 1$. Consider a linear map $L : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ and let $M$ be the $n \times n$ matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$

Recall that a change of basis for $\mathbb R^n$ can be expressed using an appropriately chosen invertible $n \times n$ matrix $B$: the matrix $M$ with respect to the new basis is $B M B^{-1}$.

Therefore, the matrix of $L$ is *unaffected by change of basis* if and only if
$$M = B M B^{-1}
$$
which is true if and only if
$$M B = B M
$$
To say this is true independent of the change of basis is equivalent to the statement that
$$M B = B M \quad\text{for all invertible $n \times n$ matrices $B$}
$$
Or, in words,

> $M$ commutes with all invertible $n \times n$ matrices.

In the language of linear transformations, this is equivalent to the statement:

> $L$ commutes with all invertible linear transformations of $\mathbb R^n$

As said in the comment of @Karl: this is clearly true if $L = \text{Id} : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ (the identity linear transformation), and it is also clealy true if $L = \lambda \, \text{Id}$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

And those are in fact the only examples. One way I can think of to prove this is using the [real Jordan form](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP274/realjord.pdf) of $M$, and to observe that if the real Jordan form is anything except a constant multiple of the identity matrix then one can explicitly construct a [*permutation* matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) that does not commute with $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another "deep reason":

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space. The set $\operatorname{End}(V)$ of endomorphisms of $V$ is a $K$-algebra, same as the space $\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n)$ of $n\times n$-matrices over $K$.

The fact that every endomorphism is representable by a matrix corresponds to the fact that there is an isomorphism of $K$-algebras $\operatorname{End}(V)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n)$. And every such isomorphism corresponds to a choice of basis. So if we are looking for basis-independent matrix representations, we need to find those endomorphisms which have the same image under every possible isomorphism $\operatorname{End}(V)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Mat}(n\times n)$.

Now if we consider the identity endomorphism, we can notice that it is the neutral element of multiplication in $\operatorname{End}(V)$. And as we know, algebra homomorphisms always send the neutral elements to the neutral elements, so the identity map is always sent to the identity matrix (and the zero matrix is always sent to the zero matrix because those are the additive identities).

Additionally, scalar multiples of the identity map are also always sent to the same matrix because any of the algebra isomorphisms must satisfy $\varphi(\lambda\operatorname{id})=\lambda \varphi(\operatorname{id})=\lambda I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $2\leq \dim V<\infty$. Assume for contradiction, that $T\in\text{End}(V)$ has the same matrix representation for any choice of basis, but $T$ is **not** a multiple of the identity. Then, $T$ cannot admit eigenvalues, by considering permutation matrices. Going to the algebraic closure, as one can always upper-triangularize a matrix to find an eigenvalue, we already get a contradiction.

But suppose we want to stick to a low-tech proof and avoid algebraic closures. Then, $T$ must be full rank, as otherwise $0$ is an eigenvalue. Consider the decomposition $T=T_1\oplus\dots\oplus T_k$ where for each $i$, $T_i:=T|_{W_i}$ where $W_i$ is a minimal $T$-invariant subspace. This means for each $i$, there is some vector $v\in W_i$, such that $\{v,Tv,...,T^{\dim W_i}v\}$ forms a basis for $V$. Since $T$ admits no eigenvalues, $\dim W_i\geq 2$. But then, the matrix representation for $T_i$ in this basis is is the permutation matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&\dots&1\\1&\dots&0\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\dots&0\end{bmatrix},$$
but clearly this is not stable under permutations for $\dim W_i \geq 2$.

Comment: An upshot to the proof I gave is that it becomes pretty explicit that it’s permutations that screw you over. It would be interesting to ask the same question, but “up to permutations”.